# Output total tests run by Jest into variable

Tags: bash, testing, jestjs

I'd like to be able to programmatically get the number of tests run by the jest command and store that in a variable so I can report metrics on it.

So the output of running the Jest command looks like this

```
Test Suites: 29 passed, 29 total
Tests:       224 passed, 224 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        287.464 s
Ran all test suites.
```

How can I store the `224` number (total tests ran)?

I've tried `jest --listTests` but that just lists the test files. The reports don't seem to contain the number of tests run, just the number and % of files, functions, and branches covered.

Comment: Why not analyzing the output of the jest command with i.e. awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine the output with awk. to get the total test numbers.

[normal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWwcD.png)

[assign the total field to a variable, total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI3p5.png):

bash command: total=$(**/command/of/jest** 2>&1 | awk '/Tests:/{print $(NF-1)}')

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Not super familiar with all the Linux/Unix commands